# Generate new keys for putty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a new private key (one that i can use with putty) 
for a specific account on my server.

i've used
"ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048" to generate a public key for that specific user but 
the public key isn't usable for putty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to use puttygen and make a new key.

You can then export it as an open ssh key and upload it to your linux machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your key with [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Load your key in there and save it as a ppk. You can then use this ppk to authenticate to your machines through PuTTY.

Comment: Puttygen wont let me load the public key, i've tried using the private key itself and it worked but i couldn't login.

Comment: That's weird, have you tried doing this from a normal linux machine as well? What do your logs say?